# "module not found" and "no such file or directory error"

Tags: arima

I am attempting to build a stock price prediction model, using a youtube video for directions. Even. though I am copying him exactly I am receiving errors such as module not found, and no such file or directory. I know this is probably something easy and stupid but can't seeem to find an answer.The images are what I Should be seeing vs what I am getting.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owWTx.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezlkM.png)

Comment: `FileNotFoundError` is exactly what it sounds like: file `data/MSFT-1Y-Hourly.csv` doesn't exist.  If you need help with "why it doesn't exist", please create [mcve] first. Also, please [don't use images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (paste the code and errors as text).

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Notebook is in "Documents/notebooks/" while your data is in "Documents/data/". You need to tell Python to go one level up to find this path:

```
pd.read_csv("../data/MSFT-1Y-Hourly.csv")
```